# Как отловить изменение (добавление/изъятие символа) в input text?

Tags: jquery

Насколько я помню, В С++ за это отвечает "change". Но в jquery change срабатывает после снятия фокуса с элемента. Так как же поймать изменение текста в input'e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**keyup**](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), [**keypress**](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/), используется точно так же как и **change**